# Access Services Timeout

Tags: list, access

When opening a large list in Access, the open is timing out at 30 seconds. The list is fairly large, smaller lists open just fine.

Any ideas on how to "open this up"?

Answer (score 2):

You "may" need to increase the http timeout limit in the IIS web config file for the web application where you have the site running with the list.

Said that, you "have" to also check the following options through Central Administration > Application Management > Manage Service Applications > Access Service Application

**Maximum Request Duration**  increase this to 300 
 
 **Maximum Session Memory**

Set the above to a considerable large number depending on the size of your list and the number of items.

Comment: in my web.config my first httpRuntime entry is

<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" />   what should I change that to?

Comment: did you check the central administration related settings as well

Comment: Yes, I already bumped those up, I'm thinking i need to tweak the httpRuntime line in the web.config

Comment: I changed the max execution on the httpRuntime and reset IIS, and it still didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: What is the size of the list in terms of item count ?

Comment: I resolved the issue, my content db needed to have the indexes reorganized.

Comment: and what did You do?